# Teradata procedure loop over query results

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to loop over the results of a first query in order to store data in an other table.
I have found on the internet a procedure and adapted it for my situation.
But it is doing nothing with no error message.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE All_AFFECT_RULES ()   
BEGIN   
   DECLARE PCI CHAR;
   DECLARE PCIcount CHAR;
   
   DECLARE Cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ID_CPTECTA FROM prod_v_mapbcg FOR READ ONLY;
 
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO PCIcount FROM prod_v_mapbcg; -- Count how many items we have to loop
 
        IF PCIcount <> 0 THEN --if you dont put this and the table is empty, you are in a never ending loop!!!
        
        OPEN Cursor1;
            Label1:
                LOOP
 
                FETCH Cursor1 INTO PCI; --Assign the next value in the list to the variable vYearNumber
 
                        -- Begin Main Query
                        INSERT INTO AFFEC_JULES
 
                        SELECT ID_CPTECTA, REG_AFFECT_NO1
                        FROM prod_v_mapbcg
                        WHERE ID_CPTECTA = PCI;
                        -- End Main Query
 
                SELECT PCIcount-1 INTO PCIcount; --decrement the loop
 
                IF PCIcount = 0 THEN -- If 0, then you've cycled all the items in the table
                        LEAVE Label1;
                END IF;
 
                END LOOP Label1;
 
            CLOSE Cursor1;
        END IF;
END;
END;
```

Best regards,

Jouvzer

Comment: Of course, you don't need a cursor at all for this INSERT/SELECT. And there's a much simpler way to loop using a FOR cursor. But the main issue is `DECLARE PCI CHAR;
   DECLARE PCIcount CHAR;` A CHAR in Teradata is a CHAR(1) and ID_CPTECTA doesn't fit and gets silently truncated. And PCIcount should be an INT, you currently get an automatic typecast from INT to CHAR and this results in a single space, which is evaluated to a zero when casted back to int.

Comment: @Jouvzer . . . I would suggest that you delete this question.  Then ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.  Your code seems to be much more complicated than necessary.